# What could be wrong with my cbr150r motorcycle?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, starter, motors

I have a cbr150R motorcycle. So basically when I cold Start it in the morning it works perfectly on a single self start. But the problem starts when I ride it for sometimes, turn the engine off and try to self start again. It won't start , not even a single sound from starting motor . All I can see a slight blink of headlight when I press ignition switch. It doesn't have a kick starter. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Do the lights come on when you get ready to start it, the starter just does nothing?

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter and ohmmeter (multimeter)?

Comment: Yes , headlight and horn works . I don't have any ohmmeter.